# JAVACV or OPENCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, javacv

I am planning to make an android image processing app. I am familiar with opencv on windows. I wanted to ask if javacv or opencv will be good. I dont want to deal with NDK. if you know any other library then please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of image processing?

Comment: edge detection, image segmentation etc